# Execute script with networking before booting Linux

Tags: linux, boot, grub2, disk-encryption, ldap

I would like to have my Linux systems use hard disks that are encrypted, and can be decrypted with some sort of key in Active Directory.

I would like the system to prompt for a username and password before booting to Linux. If these are authentic, then the hard drive is decrypted and Linux may boot.

I figure it might be possible to encrypt everything except /boot, and have Grub execute a script I could write, that would then authenticate against AD. Does Grub have this capability? Would it be better to include a small Linux kernel that does this role, before booting to the proper system, or something of that nature?

Comment: Do you want to decrypt the whole disk before booting, or do you want to pass a decryption key to Linux? First solution doesn't look realistic for plenty pf reasons.

Comment: Either/or, I just want the hard-disk encrypted so that it can't be scraped if somebody steals it or something.

Comment: So what you want is get the LUKS key from AD, which isn't really happening before the boot but during the boot.

Comment: Why exactly is the first situation unrealistic?

Comment: Also, I figured it would have to be preboot because I want to encrypt places like /etc, and I didn't think you could get very far without it

Comment: Because if this is done before Linux starts then the encryption is not the Linux one, so you are decrypting the whole disk before Linux boots. 1) think about all the I/O and 2) the disk is de-encrypted (and has to be re-encrypted on shutdown...). Linux has an accepted disk encryption scheme, better see how you can fit in. The only thing not encrypted is the kernel, but the integrity of the kernel is dealt with by EFI. Speaking of EFI, this supports some network interaction maybe you could check that.

Comment: A last warning about designing you own security scheme. Unless you are security expert (and even then) your scheme is likely to have a few holes.

Comment: Okay so if I want to store the LUKS key in LDAP, I figure I could store it as an attribute of the computer object. I've got a test VM with a LUKS-encrypted disk, what is the next step? I've searched far and wide but I can't find anybody that is doing anything similar under RHEL.